# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element' while trying to extract data text inside shadow root

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, shadow-dom

trying to scrape this website with selenium, unfortunately that text i want to extract is inside shadow root dom, like 2 of them (provide it with screenshoots https://prnt.sc/ly-T8RLVxr91) the attribute im trying to get is "user-topic-tittle" and "user-topic-line-btm"

here is my code

```
def expand_shadow_element(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root



driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
shadow = Shadow(driver)
z = shadow.chrome_driver.get('https://www.alodokter.com/komunitas/topic/penyebab-dan-cara-mengatasi-sakit-di-bawah-pusar')

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

top = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'topic-top')
topbt = expand_shadow_element(top)
btom = topbt.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'user-topic-top')
for t in btom:
    print(t.text)
```

error i got

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

so how do i get to access the shadow root dom and extract the text? im expecting to get these text https://prnt.sc/yp5H_KteB8tm

im so sorry if my question too long, im kinda new to programming. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `topic-top` element there is not a shadow-root element. that's why applying `expand_shadow_element` method on it returns nothing. So that `topbt` becomes nothing, a 'NoneType' object.

Comment: i tried using xpath 'detail-topic' is it the right one? and now im having issue with the btom

Comment: It's not clear what have you tried

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i feel like kinda messed up little bit with selecting attribute, do you know how to choose what attribute as shadow_host? escpecially in nested shadow-root like for this text https://prnt.sc/yp5H_KteB8tm 
i saw one <user-topic></user-topic> but i dont know what tag should i use as locator

Comment: I did not see shadow-dom there. There is an iframe there, right, but not a shadow-dom

Comment: my mistake, i thought shadow dom is like every tag/attribute inside shadow-root open like this https://prnt.sc/AcI15Sd0tfcR